# Rails 3: Jquery code breaks when making simple AJAX call, think is a simple mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Looking to update the User model, in the devise registrations controller.

In my view I have

```
<%= form_for(@user, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :id => 'share-form' }, :remote => true) do |f| %>  

             <%= f.check_box :facebook_share  %>
             <%= f.label :facebook_share, :class => 'submit-share' %>

            <% end %>
```

So the form has the id="share-form", I have a url and method specified.

When my Jquery is the form is submitted normally, but the database is not updated with any data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit-share').click(function() {
        $('#share-form').submit();    
    });
});
```

Console reads :

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-25 13:34:21 +0700
  Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GrQWqDseCwhlrpNhv8i3hvlL4iwae0U/pP+wSu4iabk=", "user"=>{"facebook_share"=>"0"}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 31 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 31 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('drew@drew.io')) AND ("users".id <> 31) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "authentications" WHERE ("authentications".user_id = 31)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "authentications" WHERE ("authentications".user_id = 31)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "authentications" WHERE ("authentications".user_id = 31)
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'facebookname') AND ("users".id <> 31) LIMIT 1
  Slug Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "slugs".* FROM "slugs" WHERE ("slugs".sluggable_id = 31 AND "slugs".sluggable_type = 'User') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 31 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 361ms
```

When I add this ajax call to update the data, the submit does not work and nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?? ***And the console says nothing***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit-share').click(function() {
        $('#share-form').submit(function(){
          $.ajax({
            method: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $('#share-form').serialize()
          });         
        });
    });  
});
```

I am confused, I think it has to be a simple mistake, thank you very much.

Comment: Try posting the `server log`.May be it gives an idea what is happening.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Edit to show the console info, when i remove the ajax function call the console shows nothing, like it becomes completely broken.

Comment: you're now attempting to submit the form with javascript three times - once with `remote:true` in the your view, once with `$('share-form').submit()`, and once with `$.ajax` - why???

Comment: I am new to jquery, I have never done this type of thing before. When the user selects the check box I want to submit the form. From what you said I should remove the remote:true, and are you saying I don't need the .submit function either? I thought the click would set off the submit function?

Comment: I tried removing the code and now I think I understand more, however I used $('#share-form').method and  $('#share-form').action but the console tries to send a GET to /undefined instead of reading the form???

Comment: sevencat, you seem to understand the mistake I am making here, I would much appreciate if you could answer the question with the correct query code and I can then see exactly where I am making my mistakes. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

Rails prevents random model attributes from being sent from forms and has a list of ones that will be allowed through into the `params` variable. In Rails 3, this is set via `attr_accessible` in the model. In Rails 4, it's set via the strong_params gem in the controller like [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/rails-4-strong-paremeters). If you have not set `facebook_share` as whitelisted, it will be stripped out silently.

Or...

```
:remote => true
```

Is a rails thing where it will take care of the ajax for you as long as you include the ujs script. You shouldn't need to do the Jquery bit to send the data, just to handle the returned stuff. More info [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs). If you have this enabled and are also doing some jQuery on top, there may be some conflict.

Either way:

To get an insight into what is actually coming back via AJAX, I'd recommend getting [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) installed and [enabling the debugger](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/debugging.html) so you can pause on a breakpoint in the controller and see what's happening. Tends to take the headache out of this sort of thing :)